# How to add active class on current menu item page? wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have two links: Products and News.

When i click on Products or News, it returns me an archive page that contains some posts, when i click on a post it returns me a single page of this post.

In the menu I use this code on `<li>` to add a class called active if the page is home:

```
<li<?php if(is_home()) {?> class="active"<?php } ?>>
```

But i dont know how to do it when I have two archive pages and two singles pages.

If i use `if( is_archive() || is_single() )` it'll add class on both menu itens.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    <li class="<?php if(is_single()) { echo 'single_class'; }
    elseif(is_archive()) {echo 'archive_class'; }" ?> >
```

Comment: I think you miss understood me. If i use `if( is_archive() )` or `if( is_single() )` it'll add class on both pages archive or single.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to functions.php

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item) {
if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
    if (is_single()) {
        $classes[] = 'single_active';
    } elseif (is_archive()) {
        $classes[] = 'archive_active';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
}
return $classes;
}
```